# Is rule engine suitable for validating data against set of rules?

Tags: drools, subscription, rule-engine

I am trying to design an application that allows users to create subscriptions based on different configurations - expressing their interest to receive alerts when those conditions are met.

While evaluating the options for achieving the same, I was thinking about utilizing a generic rule engine such as Drools to achieve the same. Which seemed to be a natural fit to this problem looking at an high-level. But digging deeper and giving it a bit more thought, I am doubting if Business Rule Engine is the right thing to use.

I see Rule engine as something that can select a Rule based on predefined condition and apply the Rule to that data to produce an outcome. Whereas, my requirement is to start with a data (the event that is generated) and identify based on Rules (subscriptions) configured by users to identify all the Rules (subscription) that would satisfy the event being handled. So that Alerts can be generated to all those Subscribers.

To give an example, an hypothetical subscription from an user could be, to be alerted when a product in Amazon drops below $10 in the next 7 days. Another user would have created a subscription to be notified when a product in Amazon drops below $15 within the next 30 days and also offers free one-day shipping for Prime members.

After a bit of thought, I have settled down to storing the Rules/Subscriptions in a relational DB and identifying which Subscriptions are to fire an Alert for an Event by querying against the DB.

My main reason for choosing this approach is because of the volume, as the number of Rules/Subscriptions I being with will be about 1000 complex rules, and will grow exponentially as more users are added to the system. With the query approach I can trigger a single query that can validate all Rules in one go, vs. the Rule engine approach which would require me to do multiple validations based on the number of Rules configured.

While, I know my DB approach would work (may not be efficient), I just wanted to understand if Rule Engine can be used for such purposes and be able to scale well as the number of rules increases. (Performance is of at most importance as the number of Events that are to be processed per minute will be about 1000+)

If rule engine is not the right way to approach it, what other options are there for me to explore rather than writing my own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it wrong. A standard rule engine **selects rules to execute based on the data**. The rules constraints are evaluated with the data you insert into the rule engine. If all constraints in a rule match the data, the rule is executed. I would suggest you to try Drools.

Comment: Do you mean to say, Rules engine will be suitable for my use case?

Comment: From your description, the "subscriptions" sounds like rules that could be generated based on user input. The events then could be inserted to the engine as facts. So each rule that matches the inserted event could produce an alert. You could first just try to play with some of the examples that are part of Drools repository https://github.com/kiegroup/drools.